# What are some good Spanish board games for beginners?

Tags: resource-request, spanish, group-learning, gamification

I am about to start a Spanish Learners club and I am looking for fun board games.

I remember playing apples to apples in English sometime ago and I loved it. Is there a Spanish version? Are there other similar games that are beginner friendly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any board game that involves cooperation would be great for practicing speaking to other players in Spanish.

Also, word and trivia board games are a nice way for learning new vocabulary.

#### 1. Cooperative Board Games

For a list of cooperative board games, you can check [this page on BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2023/cooperative-game).

[Forbidden Island](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/65244/forbidden-island) and [Forbidden Desert](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/136063/forbidden-desert) are good ones I’ve tried. Another popular one is [Pandemic](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/30549/pandemic).

#### 2. Word Games

[Scrabble](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/320/scrabble) is a classic that can be useful for practicing vocabulary. There is a Spanish version.

Another great one is [Codenames](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/178900/codenames). This one is also playable [online](https://codenames.game/) for free with the option for word cards in Spanish.

[Taboo](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1111/taboo) is also popular and has a Spanish version.

#### 3. Trivia Games

The most popular is Trivial Pursuit, which has several Spanish editions, e.g., [Trivial Pursuit: Genus Edición III](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/37351/trivial-pursuit-genus-edicion-iii-spain).